# How to I get to my desktop when using "python3 -m http.server 8080"?

Tags: linux

I am running a Windows Subsystem for Linux on my Win10 machine. I have another VM machine that is a windows7. When I access the localhost:8080 I want it to open to my desktop or just load my documents, music, downloads, desktop, pictures folders. Pretty much I am stuck because I do not know how to navigate to my desktop because all I see is

[directory listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orcNF.png)

I want to be able to see documents, music, downloads, desktop, pictures folders, etc. I know there is a way to dd it but I forgot how.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do windows, but you need to find the `c:\` or where ever the directories you're hoping to see in your shell, and start the `python3 -m http.server 8080` from there.

Edit:
Did some poking, you can `cd /mnt/c/Users/<USERNAME>` and start python from there ...